# PHPUnit: Code coverage for smarty templates

Tags: php, phpunit, smarty, code-coverage

Using [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de) to run tests, I'd love to have code coverage metrics for my [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) templates.

Unfortunately this doesn't work out of the box, because Smarty compiles the templates into `.php` files, so that the templates itself do not have coverage information. Looking at the compiled `.php` file coverage is not nice since the compiled files are near to unreadable.

What can I do to get the original template code annotated with coverage information?

I'd like to have a tool that integrates with [PHPUnit's PHP_CodeCoverage](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage), since I could see the coverage in its generated HTML files then. But any other solution will also suffice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essence, you are using a "new" programming language (templates) for which you don't have a coverage tool.   You've observed that you want coverage data on the templates, and yes, that has to get through to the compiled PHP files so you can run/test and get coverage data.

I don't know about ad hoc solutions, but a general solution for any language is outlined here:

[Branch Coverage for Arbitrary Languages Made Easy](http://www.semdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf).

My company builds a [family of test coverage tools](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage) based on this idea.  These tools interoperate; if you collect test coverage data from a mixed system of Java with (JNI-enabled calls on ) C code, using the Java and C test coverage tools, they can display the coverage of both the Java and C code together, sensibly, as well as provide coverage data statistics.

There's already a PHP test coverage tool in this family.  If there were a Smarty-coverage tool, its output could be combined directly with that of the PHP coverage to get coverage on both PHP and Smarty templates together.

Comment: I accept this answer since no better answer (with an existing solution) has been given.